How does jetpack compose state actually work?
So I've been trying to learn Android development with kotlin and jetpack compose. Currently going through some state stuff. So I've this state that is a list of ShoppingItem (custom class):
var sItems by remember { mutableStateOf(listOf<ShoppingItem>()) }

And I've a place in my code, where the following block is being executed:
items(sItems) {
    item ->
    
    if (item.isEditing) {
        ShoppingItemEditor(item = item, onEditComplete = {
            editedName, editedQuantity ->
            // this reassignment should rebuild the UI. That makes sense
            sItems = sItems.map{ it.copy(isEditing = false) }
            val editedItem = sItems.find{ it.id == item.id }

            // but for some reason, updating an object inside the state list is also rebuilding the UI.
            // But why? Isn't the UI only supposed to rebuild when the direct value of sItems is changed/reassigned?
            // I'm not sure though that it is actually rebuilding the UI, but the changes are being reflected in the UI
            editedItem?.let {
                it.name = editedName
                it.quantity = editedQuantity
            }
        })
    } else {
        // something else here
    }
}


data class ShoppingItem(
    val id: Int,
    var name: String,
    var quantity: Int,
    var isEditing: Boolean = false,
)

How I understand state works is that when we directly reassign the value of sItems, it will rebuild the UI. But how come changing an object inside the list is also causing the rebuild? I will really appreciate some explanation here. Thank you

I suggest that you edit your question to provide the source to ShoppingItem.

Added @CommonsWare

Maybe it is just because I am short on sleep, but I do not see how that code all lines up. editedItem would appear to have mutable name and quantity properties, but ShoppingItem is all val.

My bad! I accidentally mixed mine and the instructor's code. I've update now, please have a look

Is there any scenario where sItems = sItems.map{ it.copy(isEditing = false) } has no effect? Or, is there always an item where isEditing is true when you execute that line? In other words, how do you know that your editedItem?.let { } code is triggering recomposition?

There is always one item atleast where isEditing is true when this code is executed as the if condition states.

That is what I expected. So, how do you know that your editedItem?.let { } code is triggering recomposition? It will always recompose, because your sItems = sItems.map{ it.copy(isEditing = false) } will force recomposition. Your editedItem?.let { } code will be taken into account in that recomposition.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.
